# How to update repository access rules for Collabnet Subversion Edge via the API?

Tags: rest, collabnet, subversion-edge, access-rules

We are running CollabNet SubversionEdge.

I am scripting various tasks. One of the more obscure is updating our repository access rules to suit new branches I create. While there is a published REST API for SubversionEdge (http://help.collab.net/index.jsp?topic=/csvn/reference/svnedge_hookscripts_api.html) I wonder whether it possible to edit or replace the **repository access rules** via an API call?

(Or is that too potential insecure to expose via the API?)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether SVN Edge's REST API supports repository access rules management. However you can try VisualSVN Server if your SVN server runs on Windows - it supports access rules management automation via the [PowerShell Scripting and Automation](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/) feature. Consider the following PowerShell cmdlets:

- [`Add-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Add-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Get-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Get-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Remove-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Remove-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Select-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Select-SvnAccessRule)
- [`Set-SvnAccessRule`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Set-SvnAccessRule)

Read the article [KB99: Configuring remote administration with VisualSVN Server PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00099/) to begin using the remote administration capabilities of the cmdlets.